# Do I can pass dynamic values to gates through @can?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass dynamic values to a gate to prevent a block in blade,for ex. if I want to print even numbers through blade page.

```
@for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
 @can('print-even',$i) // i know its not possible i want to is there any other way
   <div > div to display </div>
 @endcan
@endfor
```

in AuthSerivceProvider.php

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);


    $gate->define('print-even', function($number){
        return $number % 2 == 0;
    });


}
```

like wise , i want to know is there any way to do pass dynamic values to gate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional simply adding the gate like this

```
$gate->define('print-even', function($user,$number){
    return $number % 2 == 0;
});
```

By Default the first parameter is the current Auth::user().

Comment: Thank you so much dude @Hectorda